# Access: convert US string date on Intl (French) Windows

Tags: vba, datetime, internationalization

My VBA code is reading a text file with string dates like 01-OCT-2017.

On a Windows with French or Belgian settings, using `CDate()` or `DateValue()` works perfectly for most dates, but not for FEB-APR-MAY-JUN-JUL-AUG, where "févr", "AVR", "mai", "Juin", "Juil" would be expected.
`CDate("15-JUN-2017")` for instance, will return an error.
Before I write a VBA function to handle this, I was wondering if there is some magic function that could handle this ?

Comment: This might help [How to prevent Excel to use the OS regional settings for date patterns in formulas](https://superuser.com/questions/730371/how-to-prevent-excel-to-use-the-os-regional-settings-for-date-patterns-in-formul)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the following, that seems to work well for French. Could be amended to cover all 12 month to be sure to work with other languages.

```
Function cvtUsDt(ByVal sUsDt As String) As Date
'CDate and DateValue do not work well on US text dates like 15-FEB-2017
'on machine with some non english regional settings
'problematic months: FEB-APR-MAY-JUN-JUL-AUG-DEC
    Dim sMon As String
    If sUsDt Like "*FEB*" Then
        sMon = Format(DateSerial(2017, 2, 10), "mmm")
        sUsDt = Replace(sUsDt, "FEB", sMon)

    ElseIf sUsDt Like "*APR*" Then
        sMon = Format(DateSerial(2017, 4, 10), "mmm")
        sUsDt = Replace(sUsDt, "APR", sMon)

    ElseIf sUsDt Like "*MAY*" Then
        sMon = Format(DateSerial(2017, 5, 10), "mmm")
        sUsDt = Replace(sUsDt, "MAY", sMon)

    ElseIf sUsDt Like "*JUN*" Then
        sMon = Format(DateSerial(2017, 6, 10), "mmm")
        sUsDt = Replace(sUsDt, "JUN", sMon)

    ElseIf sUsDt Like "*JUL*" Then
        sMon = Format(DateSerial(2017, 7, 10), "mmm")
        sUsDt = Replace(sUsDt, "JUL", sMon)

    ElseIf sUsDt Like "*AUG*" Then
        sMon = Format(DateSerial(2017, 8, 10), "mmm")
        sUsDt = Replace(sUsDt, "AUG", sMon)

    ElseIf sUsDt Like "*DEC*" Then
        sMon = Format(DateSerial(2017, 12, 10), "mmm")
        sUsDt = Replace(sUsDt, "DEC", sMon)
    End If

    'in case of error, return 1/1/1900
    cvtUsDt = 0
    On Error Resume Next

    cvtUsDt = CDate(sUsDt)
End Function
```